# Convert list elements in a specific vector

Tags: r, list, vector

I've like to convert a list elements in some kind of specific vector. In my example:

```
#Create a list
mylist<- list(A=c('a','b','c'),B=c(a='d',b='e',c='f'),
             C=c('g','h','i'), D=c(a='j',b='k',c='l'))
mylist
$A
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$B
  a   b   c 
"d" "e" "f" 

$C
[1] "g" "h" "i"

$D
  a   b   c 
"j" "k" "l"
```

and I need to create a specific vector:

```
myvec<-c(test[[1]],test[[2]],test[[3]],test[[4]])
```

sounds like simple this vector creation, but a have 20K list elements and is not operational type in hand `myvec<-c(test[[1]],...,test[[20000]])`.

I try without success solutions like:

```
a<-rep("test[[",4)
b<-1:4
c<-rep("]],",4)
myvector<-as.vector(interaction(a,b,c,sep=""))
```

Any tips, please?

Comment: can you do `unlist(mylist)`

Comment: What is `test` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another base R option

```
myvec_out <- c(as.matrix(as.data.frame(mylist)))
```

yields

```
> myvec_out
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l"
```

Comment: @akrun Thx, man! No worries, I just would like to provide a "weird" solution

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unlist`

```
myvec <- unlist(mylist, use.names = FALSE)
```

Or with `do.call` `c`

```
myvec <- do.call(c, myvec)
```